# Updating Users's Records in Database By Group

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table: tbl_module_bid

image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hQBN.png

you see users: Ali2,Ali,blackbone,dickface,mhmd
let's call for each one of them it's called $player and the sql query I wanna use in:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `bbcsystem`.`tbl_admin` SET games_played = games_played + 1 WHERE username = $player");
```

I tried using this script below:

```
//Update Game Played (not working very good):
    $num_qry        =   "Select DISTINCT *  From tbl_module_bid where  user = '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']."' AND module = '$mod_id'  order by bid asc";
    $get_pick       =   $db->get_results($num_qry,ARRAY_A);
                foreach($get_pick as $arr_pic)
                {
                    $player = $arr_pic['user'];
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `bbcsystem`.`tbl_admin` SET games_played = games_played + 1 WHERE username = $player");
                }
```

Well, the what im trying to do is, Take all the Usernames in tbl_module_bid and for each user inside of the table, I shall update his info (games Played) in another table,
im really new to stackoverflow and phpp..
Please Consider Helping my as a big favor to me :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_admin a
INNER JOIN tbl_module_bid b on a.username = b.user
SET a.games_played = games_played + 1
WHERE b.user = $_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']
      AND b.module = $mod_id
```

This does your both queries in one single query.

Comment: not sure if it works since im noobish at SQL, ill try it and update you :) cuz I don't want the username of the logged in member, I want all the usernames in the table :)

Comment: @user3022213 then you can try without that validation. Remove that part of the where clause. I left it because it was part of you initial query

Comment: Thank you! I added this code to the SQL database and it did it job :), but I tried to put it in php it didn't work, here is the code im using :     mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_admin a
    INNER JOIN tbl_module_bid b on a.username = b.user
    SET a.games_played = games_played + 1
    WHERE b.module = $mod_id");

Comment: yes but the php code is not working, may you please help me :(?

Comment: @user3022213. Try `... WHERE b.module = '$mod_id'");` at the end.

Comment: We need more input on your php code. I don't know where the problem is, appart from being able to update your table

Answer (score 0):

If @Filipe got it right then here is a clean version

```
<?php
$q = 'UPDATE tbl_admin AS a'
    .' INNER JOIN tbl_module_bid AS b ON a.username=b.user'
    .' SET a.games_played=games_played + 1 WHERE b.module = "'.$mod_id.'"';
$result = mysql_query($q);
```

don't forget to mark his answer as **the answer**

Comment: or even "
UPDATE tbl_admin a
  JOIN tbl_module_bid b 
    ON b.user = a.username
   SET games_played = games_played + 1 
 WHERE b.module = $mod_id;
"
and user3022213, see about deprecated functions

Comment: OMG! Thank you SO MUCH! I LOVE YOU PAL!

Comment: DUDE! mark **his answer** as **the answer**, all I did was prep it for the script... pretty please ^^

Comment: didn't I do tick it as the answer?

Comment: @user3022213. He was telling you to mark mine as the answer.lol.

Comment: oo sorry im just Dumb :c